# I can't remove and readd a front door private link origin

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door, azure-private-link

I create a front door origin pointing to my app service using a private link. This ads a private endpoint to the app service, in the pending state. I use the UI to approve it, and everything works expected.

If I delete the app service and recreate it I lose the private link. How do I get the private link again?

I've tried deleting the origin in front door and re-adding that, but the link does not appear again.

The only way I have found to do it, is to delete the entire front door resource and recreate it. This works for now, but is not a good solution once I add other apps to front door.

If you have multiple private links to the same app service, only one link will be created ([per this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/private-link#association-of-a-private-endpoint-with-an-azure-front-door-profile)). I don't have multiple, but I think the problem might have to do with how this is tracked.

Answer (score 0):

Created Front door origin pointing to my app service using a private link and approved like below:

[image]

[image]

> **Note** that when you delete and recreate an App Service that has a private endpoint connection, the private endpoint connection will also be deleted. This is due to the private endpoint connection being linked to the individual App Service instance and not to the App Services itself.

[image]

Once you recreate App service, you can add your app service in same origin host name apply and update:

[image]

Now I am able get front door private link pending request and approved like below:

[image]

[image]

> The only way I have found to do it, is to delete the entire front door resource and recreate it. This works for now but is not a good solution once I add other apps to front door.

You don't need to delete entire front door. Add your created App service in origin host name you will get new private link request and approved.

[image]

### Update

> As per [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/private-link#association-of-a-private-endpoint-with-an-azure-front-door-profile) within a single Azure Front Door profile, if two or more Private Link enabled origins are created with the same set of Private Link, resource ID and group ID, then for all such origins only one private endpoint gets created. Connections to the backend can be enabled using this private endpoint etc....

Furthermore, inside a single Azure Front Door profile, a single private endpoint is created all the different origins across different origin groups.

So, for a given resource, which is an app service in this case, Azure will check in its databases if a private endpoint is created or not for a given tuple `(resourceId, tenant, region, groupId)`. If the tuple changes, Azure creates one, or else it won't create a new private endpoint.

Now the lifetime of this private endpoint is scoped to origin and not the backend resource, which means if you delete and recreate your app service, Azure won't create a new private endpoint and if you create a new origin with the same app service, Azure won't create a new private endpoint and you don't see new connections to approve.

To ensure you get a new private endpoint connection when you create an origin with `PrivateLinkResourceId, GroupId, PrivateLinkLocation` you need to ensure you delete all the origins/origin groups under your tenant with the same `PrivateLinkResourceId, GroupId, PrivateLinkLocation`. Once all the origins/origin groups with `PrivateLinkResourceId, GroupId, PrivateLinkLocation` are deleted, Azure  will internally delete the private endpoint.

This is a known behavior at this moment.

> The Azure Front Door Product Group team is aware of this known behavior and limitation and is working on a solution but right now, we don't have an ETA for the fix.

To summarize, only deleting the origin will not help. You need to delete the origin group where the app service was added before. And also delete any other origin groups containing an origin with the same set of Private Link location, resource ID and group ID. Once the origin groups are deleted, you can recreate the origin group with the newly created app service, and you will see new private endpoint connections to approve.

To delete an origin group, it should be ***unassociated***, meaning it should not be associated to any route. refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/how-to-configure-origin#clean-up-resources)

- Now I have deleted existing app service and recreate the app service again with the same name and location.
- Edit the Azure Front Door route to disassociate the origin group you need to delete.

To do this, you can either associate any other existing origin group (which doesn't have the same set of Private Link location, resource ID and group ID) to the route or create a new dummy origin group and add this dummy origin group to the route and then disassociate the origin group you need to delete.

- Delete the origin group(s) which has the same set of Private Link location, resource ID and group ID.
- Recreate the origin group(s) with the newly created app service and enable private link.

Or I have deleted route to unassociated origin group and deleted existing origin group and added dummy origin groups like below:

[image]

[image]

Now, you I am able to see new private endpoint connections for approval within your app service. Once approved, I added routes to the origin.

[image]

Comment: This is not what happens for me. When I delete the app service I do see that the hostname is gone from the origin. When I recreate the app service, the hostname is back (I don't have to add it). However, there is not private endpoint to approve.

Comment: As mention above, when I do this the origin is automatically selected. I don't have to add it. But the private link it gone.
If I change the origin to another app service, I get the private link on that app service. Then I change it back to the original app service, and there is no private link.
I cannot get the private  link to generate, if there has already been a private link.

Comment: @DonChambers please check the updated answer